# Mat-select scroll not jumping to selected mat-option

Tags: angular, angular6, material-design

As a user when i type an option from the keyboard, the scroll bar is not positioned at the highlighted item. Also when I select the checkbox, the scroll bar scrolls to some other position other than sticking to selected option.

code is

```
<form >
   <mat-form-field  appearance="outline" floatLabel="never" class="some-class">
      <mat-select #multiselect  [compareWith]="somefn" disableOptionCentering="true" disableRipple="true" panelClass=some-class" placeholder="{{label}}" [formControl]="control" multiple class="some-class" (selectionChange)="somefn()">
      <mat-select-trigger>
         <span *ngIf="control.value?.length == allSelectedNum; else otherBlock">
         ALL
         </span>
         <ng-template #otherblock>
            ##more code
         </ng-template>
      </mat-select-trigger>
      <mat-option #allSelected [value]="'0'" (click)="someclickfn()">Select/Deselect All</mat-option>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let apple of appleList" [value]="apple" (click)="someotherclk(apple)">{{apple.name}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: you want something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fafgao?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html ?

Comment: @Abhishek I have something like that ..but the scroll bar position is not at the selected option. Say I have A to Z in the drop down. When I select K ..the scroll bar is at R.The highlight color and the checkbox select are at the right position in my case K. But the scroll bar is way in the bottom. It is confusing to the user.

Comment: can you share your code on stackblitz

Comment: @rushCoder, can you share screenshots of existing and expected outcome

Answer (score 0):

I've got same issue. For my case reason is that I changed height of my mat-option compared to original mat-option and now when selecting item material is trying to centralize or put selected item in some position, but because of changed size of all dropdown i think it's calculating position wrongly and scrolling to totally different items.

This can be reproduced even on material example
https://stackblitz.com/angular/lvlxpvkrnlk?file=app%2Fselect-optgroup-example.ts

just change style for mat-option to something like that

```
.option-style {
  height: 15px !important;
  font-size: 12px !important;
}
```

and add more items in middle and try to select something in middle
Here i tried to mulate situation: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmkqjv?file=app%2Fselect-optgroup-example.css

Comment: found this one and it's current behaviour as i understood:
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10038

Comment: Issue solved as described in comments for this issue
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/3419
additionally need to align height of lines in your styles if needed.

Comment: It doesn't work to me sadly.